# decrease font size in Telegram Messenger

Tags: lumia-640-xl

I am having **Lumia 640XL** and have installed **telegram** in it. The phone is running **Windows 10**. Is there any option available to decrease the font size in Telegram?
I have searched for options inside the application and couldn't fine one.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, currently there is no option to decrease the font size in telegram.

Telegram is not affected by the accessibility settings. It also does not have a built in option to change font size. So you are left to use the default font size.

Comment: @NeeL It is okay.